# Java AsyncTask not showing progress on UI though publishProgress(progress)

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

In my android app, i am doing time consuming task extending AsyncTask, and want to display the progress in Toast messages. Toast messages are also displayed onPre() and onPost().

I am able to display Toast messages onPre() & onPost() but not able to show onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress).

Following is my code...

```
public class MainClass extends Activity {


    public void Start(View view) {
         DemoTasks runner = new DemoTasks(this);

         runner.execute("Start");   
    }

    private class DemoTasks extends  AsyncTask<String, Integer, Integer> {

        private Context context;

        public DemoTasks(Context context){
                this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {

            publishProgress(0);

            doWork();
            Thread.sleep(5000L);

            publishProgress(100);

        } catch (Exception localException) {
            Log.d("POST", localException.getMessage());
        }


        return 100;
    } 


    @Override
      protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "post", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }


      @Override
      protected void onPreExecute() {
          Toast.makeText(context, "pre", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }


      @Override
      protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {           
          super.onProgressUpdate(progress);
          Toast.makeText(context, "progress-" + progress, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }


   }

  }
```

Also in my doInBackgroud(String...params) ...Thread.sleep is also not working.
As soon as onPre() gets executed, onPost() also executes after that!!!!

Comment: Catching generic exceptions is an extremely bad thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
showProgress ();
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        dialog.cancel();
        Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Main.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();

    }
}, 3000); //number of seconds

private ProgressDialog dialog;
     public  void showProgress () {
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        dialog.setMessage("Please wait");
        dialog.show();}
```

Bascially,you can access the UI on any method, even In `doinBackground` you can  access the UI using `runOnUIthread`.

Answer (score 0):

here is one AsyncTask Example. This will show a peogress dialog while executing the task.

```
private class LoginProcessing extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, Void> {
             private LoginCredentials myLoginCredentials;
             private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

             public LoginProcessing(LoginCredentials Credentials) {
                    super();
                    myLoginCredentials=Credentials;
                                    progressDialog.setMax(100);
                                    progressDialog.setMessage("Please Wait..");
                                    progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
                                    progressDialog.setProgress(0);
                                    progressDialog.show();
             }

             protected void onPreExecute (){

             }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Object... arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //Code to do the process in background
                return null;        
            } 
                   @Override
                   protected void onProgressUpdate(Long... progress) {
                         // int percent = (int)(100.0*(double)progress[0]/mFileLen + 0.5);
                          progressDialog.setProgress(progress);
                   }

            protected void onPostExecute(Void result){
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                //Your code after the process   
            }

         }
```

You can call this Task as,

```
new LoginProcessing(loginCredentials).execute();
```

In this Example **loginCredentials** is the parameter I am passing to the AsyncTask. You can change it to your own parameter.